# How can I send arguments through to a client from server using RemoteEvent? ROBLOX

Tags: lua, roblox

My goal here is to send the player object and the object name through to the client script to display the object name on a text label.
When I run this, it prints nil and nil. I want player.Name and name as you will see in the second code sample. Another error I get is "attempt to concatenate nil with string" from the client script.

**Here is my server-side code:**

```
script.onTouch.OnInvoke = function(button, sellObj, sellObjValue, buyObj, buyObjValue, afterWave, isLoadedPart)
    if isLoadedPart == true then
        local info = script.Parent.Parent.info
        local player = info.player.Value
        local owner = info.owner.Value
        local savedItems = info.savedItems.Value
        local builds = script.Parent.Parent.activeBuilds
        if afterWave > info.activeWave.Value then
            info.activeWave.Value = afterWave
        end
        button.Parent = savedItems.buttons
        button.jobDone.Value = true
        if sellObj ~= nil then
            sellObj.Parent = savedItems.builds
        end
        if buyObj ~= nil then
            buyObj.Parent = builds
        end
        local td = require(script.Parent.tycoonDictionary)
        if not table.find(td.boughtButtons, button.objectId.Value) then
            table.insert(td.boughtButtons, button.objectId.Value)
        end
        local ui = game.ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild('onPartLoad')
        if ui then
            ui:FireClient(player, 'buyObj.Name')
            print('yes')
        else
            print('no')
        end
    else
        local info = script.Parent.Parent.info
        local player = info.player.Value
        local owner = info.owner.Value
        local money = info.player.Value.leaderstats.Money
        local savedItems = info.savedItems.Value
        local builds = script.Parent.Parent.activeBuilds
        if money.Value >= buyObjValue or money.Value == buyObjValue then
            if afterWave > info.activeWave.Value then
                info.activeWave.Value = afterWave
            end
            button.Parent = savedItems.buttons
            button.jobDone.Value = true
            if sellObj ~= nil then
                sellObj.Parent = savedItems.builds
                money.Value += sellObjValue
            end
            if buyObj ~= nil then
                buyObj.Parent = builds
                money.Value -= buyObjValue
            end
            local td = require(script.Parent.tycoonDictionary)
            if not table.find(td.boughtButtons, button.objectId.Value) then
                table.insert(td.boughtButtons, button.objectId.Value)
                warn(td.boughtButtons)
            end
        else
            player.PlayerGui.inGame.error.label.invokeScript.errorInvoke:Invoke("Insufficient Funds")
        end
    end
    script.Parent.waveChecker.afterRun:Invoke()
end
```

**And here is my client-side code:**

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.onPartLoad.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(player, name)
    print(player.Name, name)
    print(script.Parent.Text)
    script.Parent.Text = name .. 'is loaded.'
    print(script.Parent.Text)
end)
```

Here I will tell you a little about this game. It is a tycoon that saves data using a table with all button Ids in it. When it loads, it gets the button associated with the id and fires the server code for every button. If the button is a load button, it fires the client with the player and the buyObj.Name.

Is there just a little mistake or can I not send arguments to the client at all? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Should ui:FireClient(player, 'buyObj.Name') fire for all clients, or just the one that invoked the RemoteFunction?

Comment: It should fire just the Client script that I included. - I think...

Answer (score 0):

The OnInvoke callback's first argument is always the player that fired it, so you should change line 1 of the first script to:

```lua
script.onTouch.OnInvoke = function(playerFired, button, sellObj, sellObjValue, buyObj, buyObjValue, afterWave, isLoadedPart)
```

And :FireClient() requires a player argument as its first argument, so you should change

```lua
ui:FireClient(player, 'buyObj.Name')
```

to

```lua
ui:FireClient(playerFired, player, 'buyObj.Name')
```

Comment: 2 things. One, I forgot to mention that the server script is the button script and when a button is touched, the server is fired. Second, the variable player is the Player object associated with the tycoon as an ObjectValue Value. Does that still count? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with;

First, I read through some Roblox documentation to find that the first argument I had to send when using :FireClient was the player, and because I already had the player there, it was just sending the function to that player. Now, I had 2 choices, I could send the player twice, or delete the player variable from the script. I chose the second one.

**Here is what the :FireClient line in the server script looks like now:**

```
game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild('onPartLoad'):FireClient(player, buyObj.Name)
```

**And here is what the client function script looks like now:**

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.onPartLoad.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(name)
    if name ~= 'starterFoundation' then
        script.Parent.Text = name .. ' is loaded.'
    end
end)
```

Thank you @TypeChecked for helping me realize this!